# how to call XInitThreads from Python

Tags: python, x11

I've searched a lot but cannot find this. The Python example program I have sets an X Window handle for its VLC renderer (or whatever it's called) to use, and that works, but I (1) get a message that XInitThreads should be called, and (2) clicking on the X at the upper right corner of the window does not close the window while the video is playing. If the user clicks it before the video plays, it works fine.

So I want to call XInitThreads to see if that will help -- perhaps X is somehow trapping the event generated by clicking on the X, and this will fix it.

The problem is that I have been unable to find out how Python would call the function. There are lots of mentions of it here and there, but nothing that tells me what to import so I can call it. Can someone help me out, or point me to the right documentation?

Comment: It sounds like you're focusing on that error message at a very low level. I'd suggest instead looking to the higher-level library you're using. Maybe it has an initialization function that will take care of the issue for you. Or maybe it's just buggy and you should report the issue to its developers to be improved.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into similar issue, where Qt and Tk are mixed.
Then I decided to use ctypes:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.CDLL('libX11.so.6').XInitThreads()
```